# Use pointer to member function to determine which function to call

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have the following class:

```
class Karen
{
    public:
        Karen(void);
        ~Karen(void);

        void complain(std::string level);

    private:
        void    debug(void)     const;
        void    info(void)      const;
        void    warning(void)   const;
        void    error(void)     const;
};
```

The `complain` function receives a string that can contain the words debug, info, warning or error, and it has to call the appropriate function without using a  forest of if/elseif/else, using instead pointers to member functions. The prototype of `complain` is given to me. I am new to pointers to member functions and I am not sure how to manage this. One of my attempts is this:

```
void    Karen::complain(std::string level)
{

    std::string     *p = &level;
    void            (Karen::*f)(void)       const;

    (this->*(*p))();
}
```

The syntax of the last line is incorrect, but I am trying to do `(this->*(content of pointer p))()` and I don't know how to write this. Can someone help me?

**Edit** I am only allowed to use C++98

Comment: Function names get mangled at compile-time for various reasons, so e.g., `Karen::debug` is not actually named `debug` in the end. To that point, you cannot select a function by string name to call at runtime; you need to resolve it at compile-time. Probably your teacher wants your method to receive  a function pointer instead of a string, and it's the caller's job to specify the correct one.

Comment: If `complain` is really supposed to receive a `std::string`, then you are going to need some sort of lookup mechanism to determine which function to call based on the contents of the string.  There is no way to convert a string into a pointer to member.

Comment: You could have a `std::(unordered_)map` which would map strings to functions, if that counts as "not being a forest of if/elseif/else".

Comment: An enum with a switch would make much more sense in this case...

Comment: I really wonder why you want to do this. Wouldn't it be easier to make complain a template function? like complain<DEBUG>(...)?

Comment: @mfnx how would that be any easier? You just shifted the issue to mapping between a template parameter to a member function. A set of different overloads would be simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax to call a member function via member function pointer is

```
(this->*memf)();
```

You cannot magically turn the string into a member function pointer. Sloppy speaking, names of functions do not exist at runtime. If you want such mapping you need to provide it yourself. No way around that. What you can avoid is the "forest of if-else" by using a `std::unordered_map`:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Karen
{
    public:
        void complain(std::string level) {
            static const std::unordered_map<std::string, void(Karen::*)() const>  m{
                {"debug",&Karen::debug},
                {"info",&Karen::info},
                {"warning",&Karen::warning},
                {"error",&Karen::error}
            };
            auto it = m.find(level);
            if (it == m.end()) return;
            (this->*(it->second))();
        }

    private:
        void debug(void) const { std::cout << "debug\n"; }
        void info(void) const { std::cout << "info\n"; }
        void warning(void) const { std::cout << "warning\n"; }
        void error(void) const { std::cout << "error\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Karen k;
    k.complain("info");
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oa7xzj4f6)

As mentioned in comments, you could use an enum in place of the string. When possible you should use the help of the compiler, which can diagnose a typo in an enum but not in a string. Alternatively you could directly pass a member function pointer to `complain`. Then implementation of `complain` would be trivial, no branching needed. Though this would require the methods to be public and the caller would have to deal with member function pointers.

---

If you are not allowed to use C++11 or newer you should have a serious talk with your teacher. Soon C++20 will be the de facto standard and things have changed quite a lot. I am not fluent in C++98 anymore, so here is just a quick fix of the above to get it working somehow. You cannot use `std::unordered_map` but there is `std::map` and initialization of the map is rather cumbersome:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Karen
{
    typedef void(Karen::*memf_t)() const; 
    typedef std::map<std::string,void(Karen::*)() const> map_t;

    public:
        void complain(std::string level) {
            map_t::const_iterator it = get_map().find(level);
            if (it == get_map().end()) return;
            (this->*(it->second))();
        }

    private:
        const map_t& get_map(){
            static const map_t m = construct_map();
            return m;
        }
        const map_t construct_map() {
            map_t m;
            m["debug"] = &Karen::debug;
            m["info"] = &Karen::info;
            m["warning"] = &Karen::warning;
            m["error"] = &Karen::error;
            return m;
        }
        void debug(void) const { std::cout << "debug\n"; }
        void info(void) const { std::cout << "info\n"; }
        void warning(void) const { std::cout << "warning\n"; }
        void error(void) const { std::cout << "error\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Karen k;
    k.complain("info");
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9K7rabrhz)

Comment: If I use your code, I get the following error: no instance of constructor "std::__1::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_map [with _Key=std::__1::string, _Tp=void (Karen::*)() const, _Hash=std::__1::hash<std::__1::string>, _Pred=std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::string>, _Alloc=std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::string, void (Karen::*)() const>>]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: ({...}, {...}, {...}, {...})C/C++(289). How can I solve this? P.S. The prototype of complain is given to me, so I cannot pass a member function pointer to it

Comment: @kubo did you perhaps forget the `const` ? The type of the function pointers is `void(Karen::*)() const` not `void(Karen::*)()`

Comment: @kubo hm code and error message in comments is too difficult to read. It compiles without error here: https://godbolt.org/z/ev355Yorq.

Comment: @kubo the important part of the error message is "argument types are: ({...}, {...}, {...}, {...}" but I think you simplified the important bits out of it

Comment: @kubo btw "The prototype of complain is given to me..." when there are such requirements you must mention them in the question explicitly. You now got an answer that answers the question you did ask, but not the one you wanted to ask exactly. This is bad luck, but you also should not modify the question now to make an already existing answer invalid, because thats not nice

Comment: I've tried compiling simpler unordered maps like: `std::unordered_map<std::string, int> wordMap{{ "First", 1 },{ "Second", 2 },{ "Third", 3 }};` however this gives me the same error. If I listed to the suggestion that the error gives me (writting the arguments as ({...}, {...}, {...}, {...}) ) then I get an expected expression error. What can I do?

Comment: @kubo you can open a new quesiton. or type your code here https://godbolt.org/z/oa7xzj4f6, make sure it produces the same error and give me the link (share -> short link)

Comment: Apparently unordered map is for C++11 onwards, and I am only allowed to use C++98

Comment: @kubo why that? C++98 can be considered ancient. Try with `std::map` then, but initializing the map pre C++11 is cumbersome. Actually I don't remember how it is done ;). btw thats another thing you should have mentioned in the question. Currently C++17 is assumed when no other tag is used (and soon C++20 will be the de facto standard)

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question. What does this line do? `typedef void(Karen::*memf_t)() const;`

Comment: @kubo It defines a type alias named `memf_t` for the type `void(Karen::*)() const`.  In C++11 and later, `using` is preferred over `typedef`, eg: `using memf_t = void(Karen::*)() const;`

Answer (score 0):

Let us start with the required includes.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
```

Providing the log level as a string, can lead to errors, since the compiler cannot check for typos. Hence an `enum::class` would be a better choice for determining the log level.

```
enum class LogLevel {
  DEBUG,
  INFO,
  WARNING,
  ERROR
};
```

C++ does not offer a way to obtain a function pointer given a string. After compiling and linking the function names all have been replaced by their appropriate addresses in memory. Hence, we first need to store the function pointers, in a way that allows us to look them up as needed. For this purpose you can use a static class attribute, and store the function pointers in a `std::map`.

```
class Logger
{
    public:
        Logger();
        ~Logger();

        void complain(LogLevel level);

    private:
        void debug() const;
        void info() const;
        void warning() const;
        void error() const;

        using HandlerMap = std::map<LogLevel, void (Logger::*)(void) const>;
        static HandlerMap handlers;
};

Logger::HandlerMap Logger::handlers{
  {LogLevel::DEBUG, &Logger::debug},
  {LogLevel::INFO, &Logger::info},
  {LogLevel::WARNING, &Logger::warning},
  {LogLevel::ERROR, &Logger::error}
};
```

The `complain` method then just needs to look up the correct function pointer and call the method.

```
void Logger::complain(LogLevel level) {
  assert(handlers.find(level) != handlers.end());
  (this->*handlers[level])();
}
```

The remaining functions look as follows.

```
Logger::Logger() {}
Logger::~Logger() {}

void Logger::debug() const { std::cout << "debug" << std::endl; }
void Logger::info() const { std::cout << "info" << std::endl; }
void Logger::warning() const { std::cout << "warning" << std::endl; }
void Logger::error() const { std::cout << "error" << std::endl; }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Logger k;
  k.complain(LogLevel::DEBUG);
  k.complain(LogLevel::INFO);
  k.complain(LogLevel::WARNING);
  k.complain(LogLevel::ERROR);
}
```

Note, if you insist on using strings, you can replace `LogLevel` by `std::string` and `LogLevel::<member>` by the corresponding string.

---

The same can be achived using C++98. However, you will need a bit more bootstrapping.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

enum LogLevel {
  LL_DEBUG,
  LL_INFO,
  LL_WARNING,
  LL_ERROR
};

class Logger
{
    public:
        Logger();
        ~Logger();

        void complain(LogLevel level);

        typedef std::map<LogLevel, void (Logger::*)() const> HandlerMap;

        friend struct LoggerInit;
    private:
        void debug() const;
        void info() const;
        void warning() const;
        void error() const;

        static HandlerMap handlers;
};

Logger::HandlerMap Logger::handlers = Logger::HandlerMap();

struct LoggerInit {
  LoggerInit() {
    Logger::handlers[LL_DEBUG] = &Logger::debug;
    Logger::handlers[LL_INFO] = &Logger::info;
    Logger::handlers[LL_WARNING] = &Logger::warning;
    Logger::handlers[LL_ERROR] = &Logger::error;
  }
} logger_init;

void Logger::complain(LogLevel level) {
  assert(handlers.find(level) != handlers.end());
  (this->*handlers[level])();
}

Logger::Logger() {}
Logger::~Logger() {}

void Logger::debug() const { std::cout << "debug" << std::endl; }
void Logger::info() const { std::cout << "info" << std::endl; }
void Logger::warning() const { std::cout << "warning" << std::endl; }
void Logger::error() const { std::cout << "error" << std::endl; }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Logger k;
  k.complain(LL_DEBUG);
  k.complain(LL_INFO);
  k.complain(LL_WARNING);
  k.complain(LL_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: The prototype of `complain` is given to me, and it has to take `std::string` as a parameter

Comment: @kubo Then just perform the replacement described in my last sentence.

Comment: Plus, I am only allowed to use C++98. I think map and unordered map work for C++11 onwards

Comment: @kubo `std::map` is available in C++98, `std::unordered_map` is not